# How to list the fields of a table after connecting to a bigquery database using DBI in R

Tags: r, dplyr, google-bigquery, r-dbi

I want to connect and query a bigquery database through the dplyr package in R. I know I can list all the tables in the database as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(dbi_driver(),
   project = "publicdata",
   dataset = "samples",
   billing = "887175176791"
)
DBI::dbListTables(con)

[1] "github_nested"   "github_timeline" "gsod"            "natality"        "shakespeare"     "trigrams"       
[7] "wikipedia"
```

But how do I list the column names for a particular table? I tried the following,

`DBI::dbListFields(con, "gsod")`

but I received the following error

`Error: Not yet implemented: dbListFields(Connection, character)`

Comment: As the error messages says: The dbi driver for your database does not yet support this function. Which driver do you use (to which package `dbi_driver()` does belong to?

Comment: It was from the bigrquery. Anyone figure out an alternative method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you can use something like

```
tbl <- DBI::dbGetQuery("SELECT * FROM gsod", n = 1) # or n = 0
names(tbl)
```

This will select just one (or zero) rows from the table as a data frame, with column names taken from the remote table.